# Rolling average last 3 months

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I hope you can help me with a shallange:
I have a Power BI report, where I need to make a measure (I don't have access to the source table) which calculates the rolling average for the last 3 months.
And the rolling average shall be made on the sum per month (not rolling on the date value).

Example:
in the table below, I have the "Daily Sales-Sum per month" in 2019. The datasource is one table (not a datamodel with dimensions and facts), where leaf-level is transactions by date.
I need the rolling average on the monthly sum-values.
[image]

I have tried to make the measure (please see below), but the result is wrong(table above).

DAX-Script:

```
Rolling Average 3 months = 
VAR LastDate_ = LASTDATE(Table[Calendar Day])
RETURN
AVERAGEX(
DATESINPERIOD(
'Table'[Calendar Day];
LastDate_; -3; MONTH);
SUMX(
KEEPFILTERS(VALUES('Table'[Month]));
CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Sales]))
)
)
```

the result I need is this (here shown for the last two months, as an example):
[image]

Any ideas? All inputs will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.
Br,

JayJay